# make the shell script batch render

Tags: imagemagick

I got a image magick script for rotating and giving border to an image. Now my problem is that this one making one file at a time.I want this to convert all the images in a folder. So can some one tell me how to do that. Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciable.The Image magick script is like this

```
  convert input.png;
 -bordercolor white  -border 20 \
 -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 \
 -bordercolor none  -background  none \
 \( -clone 0 -rotate `convert null: -format '%[fx:rand()*0+6]' info:` \) \
 -delete 0  -border 400x200  -gravity center \
 -crop 800x660+0+0  +repage  -flatten  -trim +repage \
 -background black \( +clone -shadow 20x2+1+1 \) +swap \
 -background none  -flatten \
 output.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the easy part:

```
for f in /path/to/dir/*.{jpg,gif,png}; do
    convert $f ... out_$f
done
```